# How do I make my 1Password extension positioning stick in Safari?

Tags: ios, safari-extensions

In IOS 8, I have the 1Password extension installed. I move it to the beginning of the queue so that it's the first item in the list of possible actions, but when I restart Safari, it's always at the end. How can I make this configuration change stick?

Comment: As far as I can tell this is a bug. The exact same behavior is occurring on my phone. (On mine it affects both the Sharing row and the Actions row.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in iOS 8 that was [fixed in version 8.1.1](https://twitter.com/1Password/status/534420430518353920)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure it matters what the position is in extensions.  It is the function that counts.  Each extension performs a different function, and when it loads seems as though it should be irrelevant, as long as it is loaded when Safari is ready to be used.

Comment: It matters to ME what the position of the extension is. It's the difference between immediately selecting the 1Password extension OR swiping to the end of the row before getting it. I'm not having a problem getting it loaded. My problem is that it's not sticking at the beginning where I placed it.

Comment: modelamac - You have not provided anything approaching a constructive answer. Whether or not you care what order they are in is irrelevant. Apple provided the ability to make the change, therefore it "matters".